# Post request session fixation

Tags: penetration-testing

I am new to the field of security, I have a basic question regarding session fixation.

Is it really possible Todo session fixation on a post request, if done how would we be able to craft a url to send to the target.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this is done through GET requests. However, there might be cases where this issue can be exploited through POST requests. That actually depends on the application itself. For example there might be an application that for some reason it accepts the session token as a parameter on a POST request and persists it for future use. Now, an attacker could create a page (on their domain) that does a POST request on the vulnerable page of the victim by setting their session token as a payload.

Another form to exploit Session Fixation over POST is by exploiting this in conjunction with a HTTP Response Splitting vulnerability or with any XSS. If the application has any HTTP Response Splitting vulnerability that is triggered over a POST request, that can be used to set the session token while the request again would be initiated by the attackers page. Same would be with an XSS vulnerability over POST.

So basically, for the cases I mentioned, the victim would need to visit the attackers malicious page (can be simple HTML + Javascript) that trigger the POST request on some vulnerable endpoint on the application.

The difference with the GET - Session Fixation is only that in GET request the victim will not have to visit a specific attackers page that does another (POST) request. But can simply be exploited by visiting the URL of the application with the session parameter set on it (eg. someweb.com/?PHPSESSIONID=123ABC).